# how can i populate a several comboboxes with the same query all at once

Tags: vb.net

how can i populate a several comboboxes with the same query all at once

```
Dim sqlmatriz1 As String = "select equipo from teams order by equipo "
Dim trasn1 As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlmatriz1, sconexionca)
Dim dtrans1 As New DataSet
trasn1.Fill(dtrans1, "teams")

With ComboBox1
    .DataSource = dtrans1.Tables.Item("teams")
    .DisplayMember = "equipo"
    .ValueMember = "equipo"
    '  .Text = ""
End With
```

I need the same for all `ComboBox`es in the form all at once 
regards

Comment: Select all the combo boxes on the form via linq. Create a Task that populates the control for each one found and finally Await all using `Task.WhenAll`

Answer (score 0):

```
 For i = 1 To 4
        Dim cbx As ComboBox = Me.Controls("Combobox" & (i))
        With cbx
            .DataSource = dtrans1.Tables.Item("teams")
            .DisplayMember = "equipo"
            .ValueMember = "equipo"
            '.Text = ""
        End With
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Sub" that takes the ComboBox name.

```
Sub populateComboBox(Byval ComboBoxName as ComboBox)
//your code
with ComboBoxName
//your code
End with
End Sub
```

And call it.

```
populateComboBox(ComboBox1);
populateComboBox(ComboBox2);
```